How to Resolve "Session expired or invalid" When Making POST Requests to Salesforce API?
I’m working with Salesforce and trying to make a POST request to the /services/data/v62.0/connect/fundraising/gifts endpoint using Apex. Here's the method I'm using to send the request:
private static HttpResponse sendApiRequest(String endpoint, String method, String payload) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod(method);
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setBody(payload);

    Http http = new Http();
    return http.send(request);
}

To construct the endpoint, I use the following:
URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v62.0/connect/fundraising/gifts' 
However, when I attempt the POST request, I get the following error:
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
Could someone guide me on how to fix this issue?
Thank you for your help!
